# Extra characters in ECDSA Key pair generation using openssl

Tags: openssl

I would like to generate public/private key pair for ECDSA algorithm using openSSL library. The problem is that after generating the key pairs, there are some extra characters, totally non-sense, in the generated keys. For example, here is the result of my code:

```
-----BEGIN EC PARAMETERS-----
MIH3AgEBMCwGByqGSM49AQECIQD/////AAAAAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAP//////////
/////zBbBCD/////AAAAAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAP///////////////AQgWsY12Ko6
k+ez671VdpiGvGUdBrDMU7D2O848PifSYEsDFQDEnTYIhucEk2pmeOETnSa3gZ9+
kARBBGsX0fLhLEJH+Lzm5WOkQPJ3A32BLeszoPShOUXYmMKWT+NC4v4af5uO5+tK
fA+eFivOM1drMV7Oy7ZAaDe/UfUCIQD/////AAAAAP//////////vOb6racXnoTz
ucrC/GMlUQIBAQ==
-----END EC PARAMETERS-----

-----BEGIN EC PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIBaAIBAQQgRcbK9JeWXghYJe0QHAaHDRrqmgX7Gp9QQrB820lHVDyggfowgfcC
AQEwLAYHKoZIzj0BAQIhAP////8AAAABAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA////////////////
MFsEIP////8AAAABAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA///////////////8BCBaxjXYqjqT57Pr
vVV2mIa8ZR0GsMxTsPY7zjw+J9JgSwMVAMSdNgiG5wSTamZ44ROdJreBn36QBEEE
axfR8uEsQkf4vOblY6RA8ncDfYEt6zOg9KE5RdiYwpZP40Li/hp/m47n60p8D54W
K84zV2sxXs7LtkBoN79R9QIhAP////8AAAAA//////////+85vqtpxeehPO5ysL8
YyVRAgEBoUQDQgAEiXKUR9yDAkmUUMj/i6LDxt0+HuMJRZWSbnq2fRZfHXgIkk9w
VFusGaX4keEJf9tOWUokEVNg1RMGfMjG9C8GUQ==
-----END EC PRIVATE KEY-----

-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBSzCCAQMGByqGSM49AgEwgfcCAQEwLAYHKoZIzj0BAQIhAP////8AAAABAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAA////////////////MFsEIP////8AAAABAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA////
///////////8BCBaxjXYqjqT57PrvVV2mIa8ZR0GsMxTsPY7zjw+J9JgSwMVAMSd
NgiG5wSTamZ44ROdJreBn36QBEEEaxfR8uEsQkf4vOblY6RA8ncDfYEt6zOg9KE5
RdiYwpZP40Li/hp/m47n60p8D54WK84zV2sxXs7LtkBoN79R9QIhAP////8AAAAA
//////////+85vqtpxeehPO5ysL8YyVRAgEBA0IABIlylEfcgwJJlFDI/4uiw8bd
Ph7jCUWVkm56tn0WXx14CJJPcFRbrBml+JHhCX/bTllKJBFTYNUTBnzIxvQvBlE=
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

I have used BIO as the I/O and here is my code:

```
EC_KEY *ecKey = EC_KEY_new();
if (ecKey == NULL) {
    // error happened in initializing new key pair
    return ERR_CODE_ECDSA_EC_KEY_NEW_EXCEPTION;
}

EC_GROUP *group = EC_GROUP_new_by_curve_name(NID_X9_62_prime256v1);
if (group == NULL) {
    // error happened in generating new group
    return ERR_CODE_ECDSA_EC_GROUP_NEW_BY_CURVE_NAME_EXCEPTION;
}
EC_KEY_set_group(ecKey, group);

if (!EC_KEY_generate_key(ecKey)) {
    // error happened in generating new key pair
    return ERR_CODE_ECDSA_EC_KEY_GENERATE_KEY;
}

BIO* memBioECKey = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());
if (memBioECKey == NULL) {
    return ERR_CODE_BIO_NEW_EXCEPTION;
}

int iRet = PEM_write_bio_ECPKParameters(memBioECKey, group);
if (!iRet) {
    return ERR_CODE_BIO_NEW_EXCEPTION;
}
iRet = PEM_write_bio_ECPrivateKey(memBioECKey, ecKey, NULL, NULL, 0, NULL, pchPassPhrase);
if (!iRet) {
    return ERR_CODE_BIO_NEW_EXCEPTION;
}

iRet = PEM_write_bio_EC_PUBKEY(memBioECKey, ecKey);
if (!iRet) {
    return ERR_CODE_BIO_NEW_EXCEPTION;
}

char* pchPriKey = NULL;
pchPriKey = new char[4096];
int iData = BIO_read(memBioECKey, pchPriKey, 4096);
strPrivateKey.assign(pchPriKey);
iPrivateKeyLen = strPrivateKey.length();
if (pchPriKey != NULL) {
    delete []pchPriKey;
    pchPriKey = NULL;
}

BIO_free_all(memBioECKey);
EC_KEY_free(ecKey);
ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);

// Return NO_ERROR to indicate NO ERROR happens
return NO_ERROR;
```

Any idea where is the problem? Am I using the BIO APIs incorrectly, or in an incorrect sequence?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you think there are problems?  Those are PEM-encoded values.  You can parse the first of them with `openssl ecparam -in [file] -text`, the second with `openssl ec -text -in [file]`, and the third with `openssl asn1parse -in [file]`.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I didn't know that this is the encoding values within PEM. Thus, how can I retrieve the EC Param, Private-key and the public key from such encoding values programmatically? I want to retrieve them in char* and send the public-key on the network.

Comment: Well, for each of those PEM_write functions you used above, there's also a PEM_read function that can get you back to EC_GROUP/EC_KEY structure, and you could transmit individual values of that.  Or you could send the entire PEM structure and let the peer call PEM_read.

Comment: The standard way to transmit a public key to a peer is to wrap the key inside an X.509 certificate and use TLS (which openssl can help with, of course).  That might be over-kill for your use case; however, anything short of that and you'll have to roll your own protocol.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Well, the reason to use BIO and PEM_write was to extract the public and private keys in char* format. I had a problem to convert BIGNUM to char*. What exactly I want to do is having the EC Param and EC Private key in char* format. I can later extract public key from that. But I don't want the encoding format of PEM. Any idea how to extract the pure keys?

Comment: Did you try BN_bn2bin?  Anyway, "char*" isn't really a format, but you're looking for the i2d/d2i functions: http://openssl.sourcearchive.com/documentation/1.0.0d-2ubuntu2/crypto_2ec_2ec_8h_a1a93f5739c093586ef83517b52b44a0c.html#a1a93f5739c093586ef83517b52b44a0c

Comment: yes I used BN_bn2hex and it didn't satisfied me. It seems it returns a 32 byte Hex while when I generate EC keys by command, it is much bigger. I used like this:

    pPrivKey = (BIGNUM*) EC_KEY_get0_private_key(ecKey);
    char* pchPrivKey = BN_bn2hex(pPrivKey);
    int nBytes = BN_num_bytes(pPrivKey);

    string strPrivKey;
    strPrivKey.assign(pchPrivKey);

Do you think it is a correct procedure to do so?

Comment: You need to step back for a second and ask yourself what you're trying to accomplish. You keep rejecting my suggestions.  Is there a reason why you are doing so?

Comment: Of course not! I just try to make my code run and that's it. I appreciate your time and your suggestion and I never want to reject them. I am just asking how to retrieve the pure keys without any encoding. Maybe I'm not expert in this area and I don't understand your feedbacks.